# Make this line table more simple

Tags: linux, openwrt, ash

im still newbie at bash/ash ,can make this sysinfo more simple

```
# display info
machine_model=$(cat /proc/device-tree/model | tr -d "\000")
echo " ──────────────────────────────────────────────────"
printf " ====D-Net Gateway Link Information===="
echo ""
printf " Device Model: \x1B[94m%s\x1B[0m" "AN OPENWRT"
echo ""
printf " SoC: \x1B[94m%s\x1B[0m" "AMLogic(R)"
echo  ""
printf " Builder: Ajie"
echo  ""
printf " Kernel Info : \x1B[94m%s\x1B[0m" "$(uname -r)"
echo ""
display " Load" "${load%% *}" "${critical_load}" "0" "" "${load#* }"
echo ""
printf " Waktu aktif: \x1B[92m%s\x1B[0m" "$time"
echo ""

display " CPU Temp " "$cpu_tempx" "80" "0" "" "°C"
echo ""
if [ -x /usr/bin/cpustat ]; then
    cpu_freq=$(/usr/bin/cpustat -F1500)
    echo -n " CPU Freq: $cpu_freq"
else
echo ""
    display " CPU Freq" "$cpu_freq" "1500" "0" " Mhz" ""
fi
echo ""

display " RAM" "$memory_usage" "70" "0" "%" " of ${memory_total}M"
echo ""
display " Swap Usage" "$swap_usage" "80" "0" "%" " of ${swap_total}M"
echo ""

display " Boot Storage" "$boot_usage" "90" "1" "%" " of $boot_total"
echo ""
display " ROOTFS" "$root_usage" "90" "1" "%" " of $root_total"
echo ""
echo " ──────────────────────────────────────────────────"
```

Output:

```
 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
 ====D-Net Gateway Link Information====
 Device Model: An OPENWRT
 SoC: AMLogic(R)
 Builder: Ajie
 Kernel Info : 5.4.185
 Load: 0.33 0.22 0.20
 Active time: 2d 17h 54m 0s
 CPU Temp : 41.0  °C
 CPU Freq: 1512 Mhz
 RAM: 32% of 1807M
 Swap Usage: 19% of 902M
 Boot Storage: 31% of 254.7M
 ROOTFS: 52% of 7.0G
 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Full of the script
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AjieDevCorp-Limited/DNetG-WRT/master/sysco-v.19

I want to be like this ,

```
 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
                ====D-Net Gateway Link Information====
 Device Model: AN OPENWRT                    CPU Temp : 41.0  °C
 SoC: AMLogic(R)                             CPU Freq: 1512 Mhz
 Builder: Ajie                               RAM: 32% of 1807M
 Kernel Info : 5.4.185                       Swap Usage: 19% of 902M
 Load: 0.33 0.22 0.20                        Boot Storage: 31% of 254.7M
 Active time: 2d 17h 54m 0s                  ROOTFS: 52% of 7.0G
 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

or longer and horizontal

anyway i using Openwrt v21.02 the display info seems to fill the screen too much and it's annoying is there a way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

This question would actually be more appropriate over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ that being said. The echo "" commands are what is causing your output to show the way it is since echo will append a newline. To get more single wider lines of output you would combine two of your printfs into into a single printf statement and use \t to create the proper spacing. For example

```
pritnf " Device Model: \x1B[94m%s\x1B[0m" "AN OPENWRT\t SoC: \x1B[94m%s\x1B[0m" "AMLogic(R)\n"
```

The \t is for inserting tab characters and \n is for newlines. I would also run your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/